# Multidimensional array in openCL with no shared memory?

Tags: multidimensional-array, opencl

Hello I am fairly new to openCL and have encountered a problem when trying to index my multidimensional arrays. From what I understand it is not possible to store a multidimensional array in the global memory, but it is possible in the local memory. However when I try to access my 2D local array it always comes back as 0.I had a look at my gpu at http://www.notebookcheck.net/NVIDIA-GeForce-GT-635M.66964.0.html and found out that I had 0 shared memory, could this be the reason? What other limitations will 0 shared memory place on my programming experience? 
I've posted a small simple program of the problem that I'm facing. 
The input is = [1,2,3,4] and I would like to store this in my 2D array.

```
    __kernel void kernel(__global float *input, __global float *output) 
     {//the input is [1,2,3,4];
      int size=2;//2by2 matrix
      int idx = get_global_id(0);
      int idy = get_global_id(1);

      __local float 2Darray[2][2];
      2Darray[idx][idy]=input[idx*size+idy];
      output[0]=2Darray[1][1];//this always returns 0, but should return 4 on the first output no?
     }
```

Comment: The shared memory referred to in the notebookcheck link has nothing to do with "shared memory" in the context of compute for an NVIDIA GPU.  Your GT-635M does indeed have "shared memory" i.e. OpenCL *local memory*.  You should be able to confirm this with an OpenCL call to retrieve device properties, i.e. [clGetDeviceInfo()](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceInfo.html) on `CL_DEVICE_LOCAL_MEM_SIZE`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
__local float 2Darray[1][1];
```

is 1 element wide, 1 element high.

```
2Darray[1][1]
```

is second row and second column which doesnt exist.

Even if it lets you have local memory without an error, it spills to global memory and gets as slow as vram bandwidth(if it doesnt fit local mem space).

Race condition:

```
output[0]=2Darray[1][1];
```

each core trying to write to same(0) index. Add

```
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE | CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
if(idx==0 && idy==0)
```

before it so only 1 thread writes to it. But this still needs synchronization instruction before that.

Comment: Edited answer. Look to the end.

Comment: Thank you kind sir this cleared some stuff up for me!